# Implicit Sharing doesn't work

Tags: community, sharing, customer-community, experience-cloud, community-cloud

We have a custom object "Request" which is a child related via lookup to Account. We also have another custom object "Submission" also linked to the Account via lookup. The objective is to send "a assessment requests" to community users for them to fill a form and assess a "Submission" for an Account. OWD is private for all these objects. Community users have Custom Community Login licenses and their profiles have CRUD access to the required objects.
The following is the object schema :

[image]

My understanding of implicit sharing according to this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_implicit_sharing.htm) is that users who have access to a "Request" record has also access the Account (Parent Implicit Sharing) related to it, and have access to the related Submissions children of the Account (Child Implicit Sharing), but my user has access to neither of them as you can see below :
[image]

Am I getting the doc wrong or is there something off ? Also do you have any alternative solution for my requirement ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you've got the doc correct, but I don't believe that implicit sharing alone is sufficient for external users. In this case, you may need to create a Sharing Set as well to grant access to the relevant records: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_setting_light_users.htm&type=5

Comment: @identigral I have two docs that say the same thing about implicit sharing in a lookup relationship where the master object is Master, provided that the OWD for the detail object is not "Controlled by Parent"

Comment: @EvanSteeSFDC that's probably the cause. I thought about sharing set and sharing rules, but the first is not possible because there is no User/Contact fields that allows that, and sharing rules are not available for Custommer Community User Licenses

Comment: Implicit sharing doesn't apply to custom objects.

Try to search: "Implicit sharing doesn't apply to custom objects."
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sharing_architecture.pdf

Comment: Thanbk you for your answer and the reference to the documentation, the one I got didn't specify if available only for Opportunities, Contacts and Cases only or for other objects as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Implicit Sharing
> Implicit sharing is automatic. You can neither turn it off, nor turn it on—it is native to the application. In other words, implicit sharing
> isn't a configurable setting; however, it's important for any architect to understand. Parent implicit sharing is providing access to
> parent records (account only) when a user has access to children opportunities, cases, or contacts for that account. Salesforce has a
> data access policy that states if a user can see a contact (or opportunity, case, or order), then the user implicitly sees the associated
> account. Child implicit sharing is providing access to an account’s child records to the account owner. This access is defined at the
> owner’s role in the role hierarchy. Child implicit sharing only applies to contact, opportunity, and case objects (children of the account).
> The access levels that can be provided are View, Edit, and No access for each of the children objects when the role is created. By
> setting to View, the account owner can implicitly see the associated object records (contact, opportunity, or case). By setting to Edit,
> the account owner can implicitly modify the associated object (contact, opportunity or case).
> **Implicit sharing doesn't apply to custom objects.**

Based on documentation: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sharing_architecture.pdf